# Is there any design pattern that allow only a specific class to new a other specific class

Tags: java, design-patterns, inner-classes

without using Inner Class

i want only class A to have the right to new Class B but i don't want to use inner class, as there is a array of class A in other class which i can not change it

There is another class holding the reference of Array of class B which will cause error while i change class B in to innerClass, as the namespace is changed. i can not change this class

Comment: A private inner class is the right way to do this. Why don't you want to use an inner class?

Comment: I think the 'only' way to do this is by an Inner Class.  However, if you use the 'friendly' modifier on your constructor you could make a Factory in the same Package as your class and use the factory to create instances of your class.

Comment: Please describe why you want to do that. There might be a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If Class A and B are the only classes in the same package then making the constructor of Class B package private would achieve what you want.

The typical way to control construction is to make B's constructor private and add a static factory method, perhaps one that takes in an instance of A?

Changing B to an interface and having A create inner classes that implement B is another option.